# Why the location return null value?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

We try to detect activity recognition and the location in an app on android studio, but the latitude longitude and speed return always null.

We already manage all the permission on the manifest, so this is not the problem.

Activity recognition instead return a value as expected.

public class ActivityRecognitionService extends Service {

```
//costanti per il canale di notifica
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "ActivityRecognitionChannel";

//costanti per il riconoscimento della posizione
private String latitude;
private String longitude;
private String speed;

LocationCallback mLocationCallback;

@Override
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(2000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                if (location != null) {
                    latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
                    longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
                    speed = String.valueOf(location.getSpeed());
                } else {
                    Log.d("Location", "Location not available");
                }
            }
        }
    };
    LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this).requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, null);

    //creazione del canale di notifica
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "Activity Recognition Channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}

//funzione che viene invocata quando parte il servizio e
//si occupa di lanciare la funzione di start per l'AR
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, createNotification());
    new Thread(
            this::startActivityRecognition
    ).start();
    return START_STICKY;
}

//funzione che viene eseguita quando il service viene distrutto
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    stopActivityRecognition();
}

//funzione che starta l'AR
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission") //permessi già richiesti e controllati in precedenza
private void startActivityRecognition() {
    ActivityRecognitionClient activityRecognitionClient = ActivityRecognition.getClient(this);
    Task<Void> task = activityRecognitionClient.requestActivityUpdates(2000, getActivityRecognitionPendingIntent());

    task.addOnSuccessListener(
            success -> Log.d("ActivityRecognition", "Start activity recognition!")
    );

    task.addOnFailureListener(
            error -> Log.e("ActivityRecognition", "Start activity recognition failed!")
    );

    LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
            .getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(location -> {
                if(location != null){
                    latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
                    longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
                    speed = String.valueOf(location.getSpeed());
                } else {
                    Log.d("Location", "Location not available");
                }
            });
}

//funzione che stoppa l'AR
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission") //permessi già richiesti e controllati in precedenza
private void stopActivityRecognition() {
    LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this).removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);

    ActivityRecognitionClient activityRecognitionClient = ActivityRecognition.getClient(this);
    Task<Void> task = activityRecognitionClient.removeActivityUpdates(getActivityRecognitionPendingIntent());

    task.addOnSuccessListener(
            success -> Log.d("ActivityRecognition", "Stop activity recognition!")
    );

    task.addOnFailureListener(
            error -> Log.e("ActivityRecognition", "Stop activity recognition failed!")
    );
}

//funzione per passare l'intent all'activityRecognitionService
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private PendingIntent getActivityRecognitionPendingIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTransitionsReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("Latitude", latitude);
    intent.putExtra("Longitude", longitude);
    intent.putExtra("Speed", speed);
    return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
}

//funzione che crea la notifica e la visualizza nella status bar
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission") //permessi già richiesti e controllati in precedenza
private Notification createNotification() {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Activity Recognition Service")
            .setContentText("Running...")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .build();

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    return notification;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

////////

Class ActivityTransitionsReceiver

```
public class ActivityTransitionsReceiver extends IntentService {

    public ActivityTransitionsReceiver() {
        super("ActivityRecognitionService");
    }


    //metodo che riceve l'intent con l'attività riconosciuta
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            String latitude = intent.getStringExtra("Latitude");
            String longitude = intent.getStringExtra("Longitude");
            String speed = intent.getStringExtra("Speed");
            if (ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent)) {
                ActivityRecognitionResult activityResult = ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent);
                if (activityResult != null) {
                    handleActivityRecognitionResult(activityResult, latitude, longitude, speed);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //metodo per la gestione dell'attività riconosciuta
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission") //permessi già richiesti e controllati in precedenza
    private void handleActivityRecognitionResult(ActivityRecognitionResult activityResult, String latitude, String longitude, String speed) {
        DetectedActivity mostProbableActivity = activityResult.getMostProbableActivity();
        int confidence = mostProbableActivity.getConfidence();
        int activityType = mostProbableActivity.getType();

        Log.i("AR", "Activity detected: " + getActivityName(activityType) + "/" + confidence + "\nLatitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude + "\nSpeed: " + speed);
    }

    //metodo per ottenere il nome della attività riconosciuta
    private String getActivityName(int activityType) {
        switch (activityType) {
            case DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE:
                return "In vehicle";
            case DetectedActivity.ON_BICYCLE:
                return "On bicycle";
            case DetectedActivity.ON_FOOT:
                return "On foot";
            case DetectedActivity.RUNNING:
                return "Running";
            case DetectedActivity.STILL:
                return "Still";
            case DetectedActivity.TILTING:
                return "Tilting";
            case DetectedActivity.WALKING:
                return "Walking";
            case DetectedActivity.UNKNOWN:
                return "Unknown";
            default:
                return "Undefined";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "We already manage all the permission on the manifest" -- are you requesting the permissions at runtime and requesting background location access?

Comment: Yes we do all the request

Comment: "the latitude longitude and speed return always null" -- which are you referring to? You have these as fields in `ActivityRecognitionService`, as data you are retrieving in `onLocationResult()`, and as `Intent` extras in `ActivityTransitionsReceiver`.

Comment: In ActivityTransitionsReceiver the three variables arrived null because in onLocationResult the object Location it's NULL, in all of the methods because when we assigned the value the Location is NULL

Comment: Try to get location using `Location currentLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();` check whether you get the location or not.